# Paint component method called multiple times whilst maximising window

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, paintcomponent

So I have created a GUI in which a user clicks a JButton to change the color of a circle... I have used the paintComponent method which I am aware will be called when the GUI is displayed and when the GUI window is minimised and then re-opened.

However when I maximise my window on mac the paintComponent method is called several times and the circle cycles through many different colours, why does this occur, as in why is the paintComponent method called multiple times.

Source Code:

GUI Class

```
   import javax.swing.*;
   import java.awt.event.*;
   import java.awt.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

JPanel row1 = new JPanel();
JPanel drawingSpace = new MyDrawPanel();
JButton colourChange = new JButton("Click here to change colors");

public Gui(){
    setTitle("Circle Colors");
    setSize(400,650);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    BorderLayout layoutMaster = new BorderLayout();
    colourChange.addActionListener(new EventHandler(this));
    setLayout(layoutMaster);


    setLayout(layoutMaster);
    row1.add(colourChange);
    add(drawingSpace, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    add(row1, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Gui createPage = new Gui();
}

}
```

EVENT HANDLING Class

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class EventHandler implements ActionListener {

Gui refRemote;

public EventHandler(Gui obj){
    refRemote = obj;
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e1){
    String buttonTitle = e1.getActionCommand();

    if(buttonTitle.equals("Click here to change colors"))
    {
        refRemote.repaint();
    }
}

}
```

DRAWING PANEL Class

```
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.*;

  public class MyDrawPanel extends JPanel {

   public void paintComponent(Graphics g1){

    Graphics2D g2D = (Graphics2D) g1;

    int red = (int) (Math.random()*256);
    int green = (int) (Math.random()*256);
    int blue = (int) (Math.random()*256);

    Color initialColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

    red = (int) (Math.random()*256);
    green = (int) (Math.random()*256);
    blue = (int) (Math.random()*256);

    Color finalColor = new Color(red, green, blue);

    ///GradientPaint gradient = new GradientPaint(50, 50, initialColor, 100, 100, finalColor);

    g2D.setPaint(initialColor);
    g2D.fillOval(100, 150, 200, 200);

}

}
```

Comment: *"why does this occur,.."* Because the JRE will call the paint methods whenever it considers a repaint necessary.  One of the (many) conditions that will invoke this behavior is changing the size of the window. *"..as in why is the paintComponent method called multiple times."*  Can honestly say I neither know nor care.  Once it is established that the paint methods should not be handling logic, it makes sense to move the logic outside them.  Then the question becomes mostly irrelevant.

Comment: I know how to fix this problem, it is simple. I just want to know why the method is called multiple times, during maximising of the window...

"I neither know, nor care", doesn't really answer the question to be fair.

Comment: *"..doesn't really answer the question to be fair."*  That's why it was really made as a comment, rather than entered as an answer.  ;)

Comment: `"...why does this occur, as in why is the paintComponent method called multiple times."` -- I don't think that it will be easy for any of us to say why the method is called X number of times, but if you strongly desire to know, then you're best bet is to scour the Java source code and also run your code with a debugger, but also try to put break points into the Java Swing library source code (I myself have never tried this), but as the other's have told you, the details of why it is called X number of times will not be needed to solve the issue, just the knowledge that this can happen and...

Comment: that it is out of our control. The solution is of course as @AndrewThompson and MrWiggles state: remove code that changes the state of your object or that has key model-type logic from `paintComponent(...)` and instead have code in the painting methods that simply displays the object's state.

Comment: Consider accepting MrWiggles's answer as well as answers to many of your other questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of changing the colour on repaint, have a specific method to change the colour that will be called from the `ActionListener`.  When `paintComponent` is called it should then just use whatever the current colour is.